# How to call method in one page behind from another page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code in "a.aspx.cs":

```
public void Flasmessage(String message)
{
    popupmessage2.Visible = true;
    string strScript = "HideCtrl('" + popupmessage2.ClientID + "','15000')";

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        this.GetType(), 
        Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
        strScript, 
        true);
}
```

I need to call it from "b.aspx.cs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the method in some common class and call it from both aspx pages.

```
public void Flasmessage(String message, string popupmessage2ClientID, Page yourPage, HtmlGenericControl popupmessage2)
{
    popupmessage2.Visible = true;
    string strScript = "HideCtrl('" + popupmessage2ClientID + "','15000')";

    yourPage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
      this.GetType(),
      Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
      strScript,
      true);
}
```

Comment: Or use a common base class for both "a.aspx" and "b.aspx" and put the function in this base class.

Comment: The problem here is I have the method in one page where it is related to header I should call the java script from that method itself. So Iam unable to put that in the common class

Comment: Hi Adil,div ID="popupmessage2" runat="server" Visible="True" class="poupmessage2" style="width: 980px;
margin: 0px auto; background-color:White;">
         
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="MessageSavedSuccessfully" class="mss"  ForeColor="black"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Image runat="server" Width="21px" Height="13px" ID="Following" 
                                            ImageUrl="images/tick.png" class="tick"/>
    </div>   For this I have the method below  public void

Comment: Flasmessage(String message)
        {
            popupmessage2.Visible = true;
            string strScript = "HideCtrl('" + popupmessage2.ClientID + "','15000')";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), strScript, true);
        }   I need to call this method in this page from several Pages b.aspx.cs,c.aspx.cs   Know I think you have clear idea

Comment: Can you put this in question. Did you try my updated answer if yes what problem you have?

Comment: It was not supporting the entire question in comment.Can you copy that into notepad you can find the continuation I tried With yours It was not working. Because the method is associated with the div.When I put that in the common class the div was not working

Comment: I pass the div as well using HtmlGenericControl can you try it now